Unexpected Overshoot with Switch Bounce
I am measuring switch bounce on a breadboard with a simple push button switch in series with a 100K resistor.  Circuit power is s 3 channel Siglent SPD 3303C.  Measurements completed with a Rigol DS1202Z-e.
The first set of measurements used CH3 of the power supply set at 3.3V.  I am seeing the expected switch bounce, however, I was not expecting such a large overshoot -  anywhere from 0.52v (3.82v) to 0.4v (3.92v).  Suspecting perhaps the power supply output was fluctuating briefly when the switch was closed, I also tried CH1 set at 6V.  The measured overshoot with that configuration was anywhere from 1.12v (7.12v) to 1.6v (7.6v).
A few milli-volts overshoot could be possibly explained with stray inductance in the circuit.  I was not expecting such large values - thoughts on what is causing the overshoot - power supply instability, scope measurement errors, stray inductance in the circuit?
A few scope screen captures:





** EDIT - Added images **

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
*** EDIT - Updates with suggestions from Accepted Answer
After cleaning up the layout, a 2.2uF capacitor was added to help filter the across the power supply. Additionally, the power leads were reduced to 12". The observed ringing was reduced significantly:

Further changes were made - a 470pF capacitor was added across the 10K resistor, further reducing the overshoot:



There is clearly oscillations from parasitic LC components. Either they are in the circuit, maybe just in the scope lead. And you are not showing the setup, or even if you are using the probes in 1x or 10x modes. Also draw the schematics. What you are seeing should not happen with such a weak 100k pull-up.

You're looking at a transient that lasts maybe half a microsecond. It's almost certainly a measurement artifact. If "breadboard" means breadboard socket, the parasitic inductance and capacitance could easily account for that.

Scope Probe is 10x

The actual real-world circuit contains "parasitic components" that are not shown in your schematic, and these are causing the unwanted ringing.  As other answers have pointed out, the wires connecting the power supply to the switch contain inductance; this inductance is proportional to the wire length, so the longer the wires the greater the inductance.  A rule of thumb is 10nH per 10mm; however, please note that this rule is only for a straight wire - estimating parasitic inductance gets more complex as the geometry of the wire changes.
To see a significant improvement in the ringing, I suggest adding a capacitor of between 100nF to 10uF (0.1uF to 10uF) to your circuit.  In your schematic, this capacitor is placed across the 3.3V power supply. This is known as a "power supply bypass capacitor".  The schematic below shows the idea here; L1 & L2 represent the parasitic inductance of the the wires to the power supply (sorry for my bad drawing); C1 is the capacitor to add.  Note that no inductors are shown in any other wires;  so on the breadboard these wires must be short.  Note also how the scope is connected, in particular the ground clip - it is placed as close as possible to the signal you want to observe.

The image below gives some idea about how to change your breadboard.  Note how the capacitor is placed close to the switch, and short wires are used to connect these three components:  C1, SW1, and R1.  The scope probe ground clip should connect to any part of the wire that connects R1 & C1, the leads of R1 or C1 are suitable for this.

After doing this two things should happen:

The overshoot amplitude should reduce dramatically, and
The frequency of the oscillation should increase - which makes
it easier to "damp out". (Hopefully this "damping out" is achieved naturally with just the existing components and wiring used in the real-world circuit, without having to add any extra components.)

A small value capacitor placed across R1 (again, keep wire lengths short as practical) will clean up any remaining unwanted ringing.  However, that extra C will also slow down the rise and fall times of the switching waveform, so select this C to suit the speed requirements of your application.  Always select rise/fall times to be only as fast as they need to be and no faster; excessively fast rise/fall times can trigger unwanted responses in other parts of your circuit & create problems.
Good luck!

After making the suggested changes to the circuit, scope probe placement and putting a small capacitor close to the switch, the overshoot amplitude decreased slightly, however, the frequency of ringing increased, but the duration of ringing was dramatically reduced.

2.2uF capacitor - overshoot ~3.7v, ringing duration - ~25nS
0.1uF capacitor - overshoot ~ 3.9v, ringing duration - ~50nS

Excellent.  A small cap across the 100k resistor will clean that up, try 100pF.

It would be good to update your post with scope waveforms showing the improvements.  Cheers.

Updated scope waveforms added.  Thanks!

@luther_stanton  OK.  What does the falling edge look like?

That looks like 20 MHz ringing.  A scope probe's ground lead and clip makes an excellent loop antenna.  It also injects an inductor into the measurement circuit.  This inductance is in series with the two inductors coming from the DC supply, also known as the power supply leads.  That, plus the probe cable and scope input capacitances, is more than enough to cause the ringing you show.
At 1 Gs (giga-samples per second), you are going to see all manner of things.  For example, the small oscillations riding on the ringing waveform could be quantizing noise, or a local TV station.
Super sexy whiz bangy ultra-wideband scopes may show you what's really there, but they don't tell you why it's there or if it really matters.

Thank you - wanting to better understand the "why it is there" led to this question!

Your wiring from scope probe to even the banana jacks are about 20cm and add the banana cables to power supply and we are in the 50cm ballpark.
The wiring, including scope cable has inductance and capacitance.
The pushing of the button is a very high speed event, the slew rate in ideal case is infinitely fast jump from 0V to 3.3V in no time at all, so expect stray capacitances to charge with high current with current limited with stray inductance of the wiring.
The transient event provides energy to the stray LC resonance which then rings for a while. You can calculate the LC value from the resonance frequency, and if you add a known capacitance and recaculate the LC value, you can estimate the L and C values of the circuit.
And, this is why it is important to protect CMOS inputs such as microcontroller GPIO pins, if you have long wire with a pushbutton at the end. The huge dI/dt causes huge dV/dt that may damage the IO pin.

Thank you - agree with protecting the GPIO pins.
